# Sonarqube restriction of a rule

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have set SonarQube to manage code quality on my project, but I have this issue:
On tests projects I don't want to run this rule:

> Source files should have a sufficient density of comment lines 
>   common-cs:InsufficientCommentDensity

How can I do this? I tried to add in Issues-> Ignore Issues in Blocks: Regular Expression for start of the block with the pattern

> using NUnit.Framework;

But no success, the rule is still appearing on test files.

Answer (score 2):

[Ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8572) created.
Meanwhile, you can either:

- deactivate the rule completely
- mark the issues flagged as won't fix
- [set an exclusion](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) on test files **for all issues**

Comment: A third option would be to [set an exclusion](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues)

Comment: you update your Quality Profile to desactive this rule. You can inherit a QP and assign it to a project